# Determining what technique to use to solve a nonhomogeneous second-order PDE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, heat-equation

$$ 
u_{tt}-u_{xx}=1-x, \space\space\space x \in (0,1)
$$ 
with the following boundary conditions:
$$
u(x,0) = x^2(1-x),
$$
$$
u_{t}(x,0) = 0,
$$
$$
u_{x}(0,t) = 0,
$$
$$
u(1,t) = 0
$$

$u_{tt}$ and $u_{xx}$ are defined respectively as the second partial derivative of $u(x,t)$ with respect to t, and the second partial derivative of $u(x,t)$ with respect to x. My first question is, I see some formulations of the wave equation use a $c^2$ coefficient in front of $u_{xx}$. How does this impact using Duhamel's integral, since that uses a 1/2c term and in my case, c = 0. What does c represent? I suspect there is a change of variables that would allow me to make this equation homogeneous, and possibly even make the boundary conditions homogeneous. I am confused on how to proceed because in every different solution I've found there seem to be extremely varied and exotic methods of solving PDEs of this type and compared to ordinary differential equations I am having trouble seeing the linear progression of these different solution types. Any help on how to proceed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why does this question tagged [tag:heat-equation] , even this question does not asking about heat equation?

Comment: It's actually inhomogeneous 1D wave equation.

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large{\rm u}\left(x, t\right) \equiv {x^{2} \over 2} - {x^{3} \over 6} + {\rm z}\left(x,t\right)}$

Comment: The $c$ you refer to represents velocity of propagation. In your case, $c$ is one; not zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Hint 1

First of all, get rid of the inhomogeneity. Recall that general solution of inhomogeneous PDE is a superposition of general solution of homogeneous PDE and particular solution of inhomogeneous PDE, so
$$
u = u^h + u^p
$$
where
$$
u^h_{tt}-u^h_{xx} = 0
$$
and
$$
u^p_{tt}-u^p_{xx} = 1 -x
$$
In this particular problem guessing particular solution is quite easy
\begin{align}
u^p &= \frac {t^2}2 - \frac {x^3}6
\end{align}
So, you can reformulate your problem as
$$
u^h_{tt} - u^h_{xx} = 0
$$
with appropriate BCs, where
\begin{align}
u^h &= u - u^p = u - \frac {t^2}2 + \frac {x^3}6 \\
u^h_t &= u_t - t \\
u^h_x &= u_x + \frac {x^2}2
\end{align}
Now you need to find BCs of homogeneous part
\begin{align}
u^h(x,0) &= u(x,0) - u^p(x,0) = x^2-x^3 + \frac {x^3}6 = x^2 \left ( 1 - \frac 56 x\right ) \\
u^h_t(x,0) &= u_t(x,0) - 0 = 0 \\
u^h_x(0,t) &= u_x(0,t) + 0 = 0 \\
u^h(1,t) &= u(1,t) - \frac {t^2}2 + \frac 16 = \frac 16 - \frac {t^2}2
\end{align}
So, now you just need to solve homogeneous wave equation with appropriate boundary and initial conditions.

### Hint 2

New problem:
$$
u_{tt} - u_{xx} = 0 \\
\begin{align}
u(x, 0) &= x^2 \left ( 1 - \frac 56 x\right ) \\
u_t(x,0) &= 0 \\
u_x(0,t) &= 0 \\
u(1,t) &= \frac 16 - \frac {t^2}2
\end{align}
$$
Equation above can be solved using separation of variables
$$
u = XT,\quad X = X(x),\ T = T(t) \\
u_{tt} - u_{xx} = XT'' - X''T = 0 \implies \frac {T''}T = \frac {X''}X = -\lambda^2
$$
each function has a solution
$$
T = C_1 \cos \lambda t + C_2 \sin \lambda t \\
X = C_3 \cos \lambda x + C_4 \sin \lambda x
$$
Now, you have $4$ unknowns and $4$ conditions to find those unknowns. Is it bit more clearer now?

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to proceed. How do I use the BC and IC in order to solve the homogeneous wave equation?

Comment: Sorry Kaster, I could really use a little help and would appreciate anything you have to say. Are these new $u^h$ supposed to be a new formulation of the boundary conditions? I tried taking partial derivatives of them in order to try to reinsert them into Utt - Uxx = 0, but I just don't understand what I am doing. I don't see how the new formulation is more useful than the original

Comment: @Pterodactyl I extended my answer a bit.

Comment: Thanks, you definitely made it clearer but I multiplied T and X together and solved for the four partials (Ut, Utt, Ux, Uxx) and then substituted the four initial and boundary conditions, but how do I actually obtain the C values? And the lambdas seem to still be indeterminate. I am sorry for asking such stupid questions but I am struggling to recall these solution techniques from ordinary differential equations

Comment: After algebraic manipulation I obtain $x(1-\frac{5x}{6}) = C_1 C_2 cos(\lambda x) + C_1 C_4 sin(\lambda x)$ $ 0 = \lambda C_1 C_2 cos(\lambda t) + \lambda C_2 C_4 sin(\lambda t) = \lambda C_2 C_3 cos(\lambda x) + \lambda C_2 C_4 sin(\lambda x)$ and finally $\frac{1}{6} - \frac{t^2}{2} = C_1 C_3 cos(\lambda t) cos(\lambda) + C_1 C_4 cos(\lambda t) sin(\lambda) + C_2 C_3 sin(\lambda t) cos(\lambda) + C_2 C_4 sin(\lambda t)sin(\lambda)$